# Need help -- could not connect to mySQL with API mySQL in c

Tags: mysql, c, database

I can't connect to the databases (in my screenshots "mydb") which I just created. [mydatabases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxPr0.png)

My code is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <MYSQL/mysql.h>



int main(void)
{
    MYSQL *conn;
    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = ""; /*password is not set in this example*/
    char *database = "mydb";

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

        /* Connect to database */
        if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
        user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)){
            printf("Failed to connect MySQL Server %s. Error: %s\n", server, mysql_error(conn));
            return 0;
        }

}
```

and the result is :[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vtw8.png)
it means : Base "mydb" unknown.

but it works for the databases "performances_schema" or "test"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The MySQL error you got was translated, and when you translated it back, it's probably not word-for-word identical. You should set your system language back to English and see what the exact error text is, because it will probably be more helpful when trying to search for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem,

i use wampserver and it takes by default mariadb and not mysql :[default sgbd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnAQ3.png) (sorry it's in french)

you can change the default sgbd between mariadb and mysql and it works. :)